# ERROR: setfield! immutable struct cannot be changed in Julia

Tags: julia

I am updating some old code and I am now getting errors: `ERROR: setfield! immutable struct cannot be changed in Julia` when I try to change the values of an immutable struct. Is there a common workaround for how I can edit/mutate those values (this may be a rather silly question given that the type is explicitly immutable so it's not a good idea generally to try and change it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I remember immutables can not be safely manipulated even if you get a memory pointer to them and try to use `ccal`.

However, as an imperfect workaround you can consider using `Setfield` package as in the example below.

```
using Setfield
struct S
    a::Int
    b::String
end
```

Using:

```
julia> s = S(2, "hello")
S(2, "hello")

julia> s = @set s.a = 5
S(5, "hello")
```

Note that in many scenarios this might be faster than actually changing type of S to `mutable`.

Comment: This is a great answer! @LoganKilpatrick in julia 1.0 structs became immutable by default, and this package is a good way for working with immutable data.